# Jflex capturing match

Tags: regex, jflex

I'm using `JFlex` and i want to match something like:

```
|MATCHED|NOTMACHED|
|NOTMACHED|NOTMACHED|NOTMACHED|
<newline>
|MATCHED|NOTMACHED|
|NOTMACHED|NOTMACHED|NOTMACHED|
```

my pattern:

```
 FIXTURE_NAME_PATTERN=[^\|]\n\|[A-Za-z]+\|


 <YYINITIAL> {FIXTURE_NAME}
  { yybegin(YYINITIAL); return FitnesseTypes.FIXTURE_NAME; }
```

But it matches pipes "`|`" aswell as previous lines (whitespaces). I tried to use capturing but i can't get this working. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use states. Define a state such as

```
%state AFTER_NEWLINE
```

in your state definitions.

Then, in your lexical definitions, you would have something like this:

```
<YYINITIAL>\n
{ yybegin(AFTER_NEWLINE); }

<AFTER_NEWLINE>|
{ /*Do whatever you want with pipes*/ }

<AFTER_NEWLINE>[A-Za-z]
{ yybegin(YYINITIAL); return FitnesseTypes.FIXTURE_NAME; }

//Any other lexical definitions you might need
```

What this basically does is every time a new line is hit, it sets the state to AFTER_NEWLINE. Then, it matches the next time a bunch of letters show up in a row, and sets the state back to YYINITIAL. Pipes are thrown away.